# Why is so slow when use Spark Cassandra Connector in java code with Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

we have tested a lot in many scenes in small data.

if use cassandra installed without cluster，then everything is ok，but if we use cassandra in cluster，then it will cost more then about 15 seconds at the same function.

Our java code is just as the sample code.Purely,  call the dataset.collectAsList() or dataset.head(10)。

But if we use scala ，the same logic in spark-shell don't have the problem.

We have test a lot jdks and systems.Mac OS is fine, but window OS and linux OS like centos both have this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have Cassandra in a cluster, not single node, then data scan will affect multiple machine, plus overhead for query planning, etc.  You can use `.explain()` on the DataFrame object to see explanation of your query

Comment: this is not help.we get the java stack log by skywalking，and the time not cause in querying. the time cause in getHostName.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

collectAsList or head function，will try to getHostName，this is a expensive operation.So we can't use Ip to connect cassandra cluster, we have to use HOSTNAME to connect it.And it works!!!! the code of spark cassandra connector have to fix this problems.

Comment: it looks like more a problem with your DNS. I've never had such problem using spark cassandra connector for many years